# How to get value from directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I neeed to pass a value from this part of the code in my directive to a controller, but not sure how to achieve that:

```
       if (!scope.multiple) {
          scope.model = value;
          console.log(scope.model);
          return;
        }
```

I get the value in the console.log, I just don't know how to pass it to the controller.
This is the complete directive:

```
angular.module('quiz.directives')
.directive('fancySelect', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/directives/fancySelect.html',
    scope: {
      title: '@',
      model: '=',
      options: '=',
      multiple: '=',
      enable: '=',
      onChange: '&',
      class: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.showOptions = false;
      scope.displayValues = [];

      scope.$watch('enable', function(enable) {
        if (!enable && scope.showOptions) {
          scope.toggleShowOptions(false);
        }
      });

      scope.toggleShowOptions = function(show) {
        if (!scope.enable) {
          return;
        }

        if (show === undefined) {
          show = !scope.showOptions;
        }

        if (show) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('fancySelect:hideAll');
        }

        $timeout(function() {
          scope.showOptions = show;
        });
      };

      scope.toggleValue = function(value) {
        if (!value) {
          return;
        }

        if (!scope.multiple) {
          scope.model = value;
          console.log(scope.model);
          return;
        }

        var index = scope.model.indexOf(value);
        if (index >= 0) {
          scope.model.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else {
          scope.model.push(value);
        }

        if (scope.onChange) {
          scope.onChange();
        }
      };

      scope.getDisplayValues = function() {
        if (!scope.options || !scope.model) {
          return [];
        }

        if (!scope.multiple && scope.model) {
          return scope.options.filter(function(opt) {
            return opt.id == scope.model;
          });
        }

        return scope.options.filter(function(opt) {
          return scope.model.indexOf(opt.id) >= 0;
        });
      };

      $rootScope.$on('fancySelect:hideAll', function() {
        scope.showOptions = false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Updated**

I tried to do as suggested in the answers by @Zidane and defining my object first in the controller like this:

```
$scope.year = {};

var saveUser = function(user) {
   $scope.profilePromise = UserService.save(user);
console.log($scope.year);
```

This is the template:

```
<fancy-select
            title="Klassetrinn"
            model="year"
            options="years"
            enable="true"
            on-change="onChangeYears()"
            active="yearsActive"
            name="playerYear"
            form-name="registerForm"
          >
          </fancy-select>
```

But I got an empty object in that case.

When I define my objects like this I get the right value in the controller but in the view the title is not being displayed anymore:

```
$scope.search = {
    years: []
  };

var saveUser = function(user) {
    $scope.profilePromise = UserService.save(user);
console.log($scope.search.years);

<fancy-select
            title="Klassetrinn"
            model="search.years"
            options="years"
            enable="true"
            on-change="onChangeYears()"
            active="yearsActive"
            name="playerYear"
            form-name="registerForm"
          >
          </fancy-select>
```

Comment: Not sure that completely understand your question, do you want to bind value to ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

As you defined an isolated scope for your directive like this

```
scope: {
      ...
      model: '=',
      ...
    },
```

you give your directive a reference to an object on your controller scope.
Declaring the directive like `<fancy-select model="myModel" ....></fancy-select>` you pass your directive a reference to `scope.myModel` on your controller. When you modify a property on the `scope.model` object in your directive you automatically modify the same property on the `scope.myModel` object in your controller.

So you have to do

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.myModel = {};
  ...
}
```

in your controller and in your directive just do

```
if (!scope.multiple) {
  scope.model.value = value;
  return;
}
```

**Then you can get the value in your controller via `$scope.myModel.value`.**

For clarification: You have to define an object on your controller and pass the directive the reference for this object so that the directive can follow the reference and doesn't mask it. If you did in your directive `scope.model = 33` then you would just mask the reference passed to it from the controller, which means `scope.model` wouldn't point to the object on the controller anymore. When you do `scope.model.value = 33` then you actually follow the object reference and modify the object on the controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can use services or factories to share data between your angular application parts,  for example

```
    angular.module('myapp').factory('myDataSharing', myDataSharing);

function myDataSharing() {


    var sharedData = {
        fieldOne: ''
    };

    return {
        setData: setData,
        getData: getData,
    };


    function setData(dataFieldValue) {
        sharedData.fieldOne = dataFieldValue;
    };


    function getData() {
        sharedData.fieldOne
    };


    directive:
        myDataSharing.setData(dataValue);

    controller:
angular.module('myapp').controller('myController' ['myDataSharing'], function(myDataSharing) {
            var myDataFromSharedService = myDataSharing.getData();
        }
```